# What is the difference between "switch" and "filter" in Tracing in .NET?

Tags: .net, filter, switch-statement, trace, system.diagnostics

What is the difference between "switch" and "filter" in Tracing in .NET ? They seem to work in similar way.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="5">
      <listeners>
        <add name="DemoListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\output1.txt">
        </add>
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>    
    <sources>
      <source name="DemoApp" switchName="DemoApp">
        <listeners>
          <add name="DemoListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\output2.txt">
            <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Error"/>
          </add>
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DemoApp" value="Error"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bit of overlap.  A `<filter>` names a specific class that you write that's derived from TraceFilter.  Which you can use to suppress trace output, anything is possible.  It always applies to a specific TraceListener.

The `<switches>` element is useful to configure tracing and set the value of a TraceSwitch object.  Which you then test in your code to selectively bypass trace output.  Note how `<switches>` is "global", it doesn't apply to a specific listener.  So a logical place to test the switch is in the TraceSource.  A good use for a switch is to configure the tracing verbosity.  Like your "Error" value would indicate that only errors are ever traced.

Comment: In other words the `<switch>` element restricts the input messages sent to the listeners and the `<filter>` element restricts the messages the listener outputs.