# Trace & Log to file using TraceSource

Tags: c#, logging, trace

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC web app, using System.Diagnostics.TraceSource to trace and log to file. Added following to web.config

```
 <system.diagnostics>    
  <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4"></trace> // what's this for?  
  <sources>    
    <source name ="WebAppLog">    
      <listeners>    
        <add name="FileLog" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="PartialView_WebApp.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime,ThreadId,ProcessId,Timestamp,LogicalOperationStack,Callstack">    
          <filter initializeData="All" type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"/>    
        </add>    
        <remove name="Default"/>    
      </listeners>    
    </source>    
  </sources>    
</system.diagnostics>
```

Added Log.cs to application to log mesages to file.

```
public class Log  
{  
    static TraceSource source = new TraceSource("WebAppLog"); 
    public static void Message(TraceEventType traceEventType, string message)  
    {  
        short id;  
        switch (traceEventType)  
        {  
            case TraceEventType.Information:  
                id = 3;  
                break;  
            case TraceEventType.Verbose:  
                id = 4;  
                break;  
            default:  
                id = -1;  
                break;  
        }  
        source.TraceEvent(traceEventType, id, message);  
        source.Flush();    
    }
}
```

*Home controller.cs*

```
public ActionResult Index()  
{  
    try  
    {  
        Log.Message(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, "Index Action Start");
        // Do work
        Log.Message(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, "Index Action End");  
        return View();  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {
        throw;  
    }  
}
```

After executing, i'm able to generate log file but couldn't write anything, always the file size is **0 bytes**. *What could be the possible mistake.?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Switch` on a `TraceSource` determines whether any output gets generated.
By default, if it is not configured, there will be no output.

The value for the `Switch` matches the log levels that should appear in the output.

It can be set via code:

```
static TraceSource source = new TraceSource("WebAppLog"); 
source.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Verbose;
```

Or via configuration, which is more flexible.
Your configuration will look like:

```
<system.diagnostics>    
     <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4"></trace> 
     <sources>    
         <source name ="WebAppLog" switchName="mySwitch">    
             <listeners>    
                 <add name="FileLog" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\tmp\trace.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime,ThreadId,ProcessId,Timestamp,LogicalOperationStack,Callstack">    
                     <filter initializeData="All" type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"/>
                 </add>    
                 <remove name="Default"/>
             </listeners>    
        </source>    
    </sources>    
    <switches>
        <add name="mySwitch" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

---

Regarding your question about

```
<trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4"></trace>
```

With `autoflush=true` you don't have to call `source.Flush()` explicitly.
The `indentsize` gets applied in the log output, notice the leading whitespace starting from line 2 in the output fragment below.

```
WebAppLog Information: 3: Index Action Start
    ProcessId=7416
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=1
```

Comment: Appreciate your response @pfx, may i know what is this line `<filter initializeData="All" type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"/>` doing here.?, as per my understanding, the listener `TextWriterTraceListener` filters based on the event type. So if i change to `initializeData="Error"` will this only log Error messages to file.? if so, what is `value="Verbose"` under `switches` doing?
Please elaborate this, so that i can understand what's each attribute doing here.

Comment: A `Switch` acts as a filter for a `TraceSource`. A `Filter` acts as a filter for a `Listener`. When using only a single `TraceSource`, I mostly only apply a `Switch`. When it is configured with `value="Error"` then `source.TraceData(TraceEventType.Verbose ...` does not appear in the output. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742595/what-is-the-difference-between-switch-and-filter-in-tracing-in-net).